# O que eh o erro no DEBUG: java.net.socketExeption "socket Closed"?

Tags: android

Ontem meu APP de estudos rodava tranquilamente, terminei, fiz BKP e fui pra casa...   
**Hoje** abri e fui direto rodar pra conferir tudo... mas, sem mais nem menos,  recebi esse erro no console do debug.....

```
Unable to open debug port (127.0.0.1:57709): java.net.socketExeption "socket Closed"
```

Tem varios tutores na net, falando que tem outro processo usando essa porta, entao,
1) **Abri o COMMAND e dei um:**

```
netstat -a
```

Mas nao tem nada usando essa porta...
Fechei o Android Studio e repeti o processo... e nao tem nada usando essa porta 
MESMO.

Re-abri tudo e o erro continua...

2) **OUTRO teste que fiz**, foi desligar o firewall completamente, pra ter certeza...
mas nao deu qualquer resultado..
O erro continua...

O que poder ser?
Não tenho a menor ideia do que fazer...

Eis a minha tela de trabalho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostra alguma linha no código onde está dando erro?

Comment: Nao.. nada de erro em lugar algum...  outros colegas de trabalho.. no mesmo projeto... nao tem qualquer problema...  e eh exatamente a mesma versao....

Comment: você executa o projeto direto num dispositivo físico?

Comment: Sim!  mas lembrando que o erro... acontece um pouco ANTES de enviar para o CEL...  ainda na compilacao do APP.. no Android Studio, Na verade ELE APARECE, logo apos de clicar no botao "Debug app"  que manda rodar no CEL no "modo debug"

Comment: Minha sugestão é que esta rodando a task errada do gradle. No seu print, lá no barra de ferramentas, esta rodando `rakuseki[signingReport]`, deve escolher `app` no lugar.

Comment: aoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo  nossa..... nem tinha percebido issooooo ...  AFE...  ser noob eh complicado!!  BRIGADAAA! ..  AFE..  que peso saiu de mim agora..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No android, para referenciar a rede local, você deve usar o endereço: `10.0.2.2:8080` porque o emulador do android roda em uma máquina virtual, portanto, `127.0.0.1` ou "localhost" será o mesmo endereço do emulador.

Comment: mmmm...  eu nao uso o emulador...  uso um cel mesmo... e nesse meu dispositivo (android) tanto como no meu micro (Win10), não configuro o IP.... eles pegam direto do DHCP.... da rede...  (wifi ou 4G) !!!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto Podes mandar um print do teu android Studio? Pode ser da tela principal mesmo

Comment: Pronto! coloquei na pergunta!  Obrigada pela pasciencia!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto Veja esse link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766228/unable-to-open-debugger-port-java-net-socketexception-socket-closed) se te ajuda, pelo que entendi, basta você alterar o modo de debugger

Comment: simmm! eh isso mesmo!!!  nossa!!!   brigadaaaaaa!